# Navigation Experimental is unmounting Tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation, react-native

I am working on a react native app that uses Composite Experimental Navigation (CardStack + Tabs) and redux for state management. I was able to create Tab based Navigation but the issue that i am facing now is when i switch between tabs the component is unmounted and it re-render every time.

**Problems**

Lets say i have scrolled down several posts and when i change Tab it will start from top. (Workaround could be to store scroll position in redux state).

Here is the sample code i am using for Navigation [Tabbed Experimental Navigation](https://github.com/nak1b/react-native-composite-navigation)

Comment: I have used NavigationIOS and TabBarIOS. The component does not unmount while switching between tabs.

Answer (score 4):

You must change approach for TabBar.

Basically you want Navigator per Tab, so you can have route stack for each Tab and one Navigator to contain Tabs (TabBar). You also want to set initial route stack for TabBar and jump between those routes.

It is important to understand difference between Navigator methods.

- When you `pop` route, it's unmounted, and active index is moved to
  last one. As last one is kept in state it will be restored as it was
  previously rendered (most likely, it can happen props changed). Going    again to `popped` route will rerender scene entirely (this happens to you).
- When you `push` route, nothing is unmounted, new route is mounted.
- When you `jumpToIndex` route, again nothing in unmounted, thus jumping
  between routes restores scenes as they were (again, if props changed
  scene will be rerendered).

So, I don't think this is correct:

> I was able to create Tab based Navigation but the issue that i am facing now is when i switch between tabs the component is unmounted and it re-render every time.

... you unmount routes with wrong navigation actions.

Also what is different now, `NavigationCardStack` doesn't actual create it's own state, it is passed from outside, which gives you great flexibility. And also good thing is that you can use reducers provided by Facebook for common actions (such as push, pop, jumpToIndex; they are part of Navigation Utils).

You have full example on how to create `navigationState` and it reducers [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html), so I am not going to explain that, just going to give idea how to solve your problem.

#### [UPDATE] Example works now!

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationExperimental, View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const {
  CardStack: NavigationCardStack,
  StateUtils: NavigationStateUtils,
} = NavigationExperimental;

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  screenTitle: {
    marginTop: 50,
    fontSize: 18,
  },
  pushNewScreenLabel: {
    marginVertical: 10,
    fontSize: 15,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  goBackLabel: {
    fontSize: 15,
  },
  tabBarWrapper: {
    position: 'absolute',
    height: 50,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    top: null,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 0,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  },
  tabBarItem: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
});

export class TabBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.jumpToTab = this.jumpToTab.bind(this);

    // Create state
    this.state = {
      navigationState: {
        // Active route, will  be rendered as default
        index: 0,
        // "tab-s" represents route objects
        routes: [
          { name: 'Tab1', key: '1' },
          { name: 'Tab2', key: '2' },
          { name: 'Tab3', key: '3' },
          { name: 'Tab4', key: '4' }],
      },
    };
  }

  jumpToTab(tabIndex) {
    const navigationState = NavigationStateUtils.jumpToIndex(this.state.navigationState, tabIndex);
    this.setState({ navigationState });
  }

  renderScene({ scene }) {
    return <Tab tab={scene.route} />;
  }

  render() {
    const { navigationState } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={style.screen}>
        <NavigationCardStack
          onNavigate={() => {}}
          navigationState={navigationState}
          renderScene={this.renderScene}
        />
        <View style={style.tabBarWrapper}>
          {navigationState.routes.map((route, index) => (
            <TabBarItem
              key={index}
              onPress={this.jumpToTab}
              title={route.name}
              index={index}
            />
            ))}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class TabBarItem extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    title: React.PropTypes.string,
    onPress: React.PropTypes.func,
    index: React.PropTypes.number,
  }

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this);
  }
  onPress() {
    this.props.onPress(this.props.index);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Text style={style.tabBarItem} onPress={this.onPress}>
        {this.props.title}
      </Text>);
  }
}

class Tab extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    tab: React.PropTypes.object,
  }

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.goBack = this.goBack.bind(this);
    this.pushRoute = this.pushRoute.bind(this);
    this.renderScene = this.renderScene.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      navigationState: {
        index: 0,
        routes: [{ key: '0' }],
      },
    };
  }

  // As in TabBar use NavigationUtils for this 2 methods
  goBack() {
    const navigationState = NavigationStateUtils.pop(this.state.navigationState);
    this.setState({ navigationState });
  }

  pushRoute(route) {
    const navigationState = NavigationStateUtils.push(this.state.navigationState, route);
    this.setState({ navigationState });
  }

  renderScene({ scene }) {
    return (
      <Screen
        goBack={this.goBack}
        goTo={this.pushRoute}
        tab={this.props.tab}
        screenKey={scene.route.key}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationCardStack
        onNavigate={() => {}}
        navigationState={this.state.navigationState}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
      />
    );
  }
}

class Screen extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    goTo: React.PropTypes.func,
    goBack: React.PropTypes.func,
    screenKey: React.PropTypes.string,
    tab: React.PropTypes.object,
  }

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.nextScreen = this.nextScreen.bind(this);
  }

  nextScreen() {
    const { goTo, screenKey } = this.props;
    goTo({ key: `${parseInt(screenKey) + 1}` });
  }

  render() {
    const { tab, goBack, screenKey } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={style.screen}>
        <Text style={style.screenTitle}>
          {`Tab ${tab.key} - Screen ${screenKey}`}
        </Text>
        <Text style={style.pushNewScreenLabel} onPress={this.nextScreen}>
          Push Screen into this Tab
        </Text>
        <Text style={style.goBackLabel} onPress={goBack}>
          Go back
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

## TBD little more clean up..

Comment: thats exactly how i was able to solve the problem. What i did was rendering 4 separate NavigationCardStack for 4 different Tab. Before i was using single CardStack for all 4 tabs. So on changing tabs, navigation reducer would change the state and the NavigatorCardStack would re-render the scenes

Comment: @Nakib would you mind sharing your approach?  I'm having the same issue you describe in your original question and using a navigator per tab hasn't solved it for me.

Comment: @ElliottBorealis i changed my code to use TabBarIOS and seperate card stack per tab.  I am not sure if it will work without TabBarIOS

Comment: @Nakib Yeah, I had already done the same but was hoping it could be done without the `TabBarIOS`. FYI I've been using the `TabBarIOS` approach with only one `NavigationCardStack` though and it works just fine. That being said, there has to be a way to achieve the `TabBarIOS` tab switching experience using just `NavigationExperimental`, in particular for cross platform apps.

Comment: I'll find time later today and create working example as I see this is actual :)

Comment: @ElliottBorealis can you share your code with single NavigationCardStack and TabBarIOS

Comment: @MrBr that would be great

Comment: I have update code, it works now. Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: @MrBr Thanks for the detailed code sample above. However, the navigation is a bit buggy. First of all, when navigating from Tab 1 to Tab 4, Tab 2 and Tab 3 become visible during the animation. Second, there shouldn't be any animation when navigating between tabs, only when pushing a new scene onto an existing tab. 

What I would want is seamless transition between tabs like in the Facebook UIExplorer > Navigation (Experimental) > CardStack + Header + Tabs example but with each tab mounted (e.g. to retain scroll position) like in your example. Best of both worlds.

Comment: When you pass `NavigationCardStack` the entire `navigationState` you get this buggy animation. When you pass it a substate with only the selected route you get the desired tabbing experience but loose the scroll position. Something like `{index: 0, routes: [{name: 'Tab4', key: '4'}]` if Tab4 is selected.

Comment: @ElliottBorealis you do not understand the concept. By passing what you wrote, you are not passing substate, that is whole state and because you are replacing whole state you are loosing old screens. Read about NavigationExperimental navigation state reduces. Considering animations, it is default behavior of NavigationStack, I didn't have time to find a way to remove transitions.

Comment: @MrBr This is how it's done in the UIExplorer example I referenced above. I'm sorry for the wording, I realise that to the `NavigationCardStack` this is the entire state but it is still only a k-v pair of the entire app navigation state in the aforementioned example. I also realise that scenes not passed will be lost. 

The problem remains that if you jump from scene 0 to scene N while passing every scene in between to the CardStack you will get this faulty animation.  Am I wrong to assume that this is because the approach is wrong rather than it being a matter of customizing the animation?